# Get value from another Oracle sequence if one sequence has reached its max value

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have a oracle sequence named SEQ_A ranging from 1 to 100.
I want to handle my JPA code in such a way that if range in SEQ_A has reached max number than the application should read from SEQ_B and if SEQ_B has reached max number then it should read from SEQ_C and so on.

How should I handle this in Java code using JPA.

```
@Repository
public interface SequenceRepository extends JpaRepository<SeqValue, Long>{

@Query(value = "select 'A' || SEQ_A.nextval from dual", native = true)
Long getNextSequence();

}
```

SeqValue class:

```
@Entity
public class SeqValue{

@Id
private Long id;

private Long sequenceValue;

//constructor, getter, setter
}
```

In my service class, I am calling getNextSequence() and appending prefix A to sequence number, how do I make sure that if SEQ_A has reached max limit (say 100), then it should use SEQ_B and append prefix B to sequence number and once B has reached its limit then use SEQ_C and so on.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than maintaining multiple sequences, including possibly having to add more and adjust whatever logic you come up with when you need more values, you could have a single sequence and manipulate its value to format the result how you want. That can be done in two parts; truncating the sequence value / 100 and adding the result to 65 gives you an ASCII code for A, B, C etc, which you can convert to that character with the `chr()` function; and taking the modulus of the value gives the remainder (adjusting slightly so you get 1-100 rather than 0-99):

```
select chr(trunc((one_seq.nextval - 1) / 100) + 65)
  || to_char(mod(one_seq.nextval - 1, 100) + 1) as value
from dual
```

Which generates

| VALUE |
| --- |
| A1 |
| A2 |
| A3 |
| ... |
| A98 |
| A99 |
| A100 |
| B1 |
| B2 |
| B3 |
| ... |
| B98 |
| B99 |
| B100 |
| C1 |
| C2 |
| C3 |
| ... |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/y-Afhw8r)

You can also then easily format the numeric part to three digits if you want to, by adding the `FM000` format model:

```
select chr(trunc((one_seq.nextval - 1) / 100) + 65)
  || to_char(mod(one_seq.nextval - 1, 100) + 1, 'FM000') as value
from dual
```

| VALUE |
| --- |
| A001 |
| A002 |
| A003 |
| ... |
| A098 |
| A099 |
| A100 |
| B001 |
| B002 |
| B003 |
| ... |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/ZLDKxyMj)

However, you need to be aware that sequences are not (and are not designed to be) gapless, and may not always be generated in the order you expect, so they may not be suitable for this. It depends partly on how you'll use the values and add data going forward.

And, of course, you'll still run into problems when you reach 2600 values, as you'll go from `Z100` to `[001` since `[` is the next ASCII character.

| VALUE |
| --- |
| Z098 |
| Z099 |
| Z100 |
| [001 |
| [002 |
| [003 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/rQoj78qy)

That will be an issue however you approach this though.

---

> after Z100 can we add some logic to start at AA001 to overcome the 2600 value limitation

You can, but it gets a bit messy; with a bit pf playing around you can do this, modified from the previous version to start the sequence from 0 instead of 1 to simplify it slightly:

```
select case when one_seq.nextval - 100 >= (26 * 100)
    then chr(mod(trunc((one_seq.nextval - 100) / (26 * 100)) - 1, 26) + 65) end
  || case when one_seq.nextval >= 100
    then chr(mod(trunc((one_seq.nextval - 100) / 100), 26) + 65) end
  || to_char(mod(one_seq.nextval, 100) + 1, 'FM000') as value
from dual
```

| VALUE |
| --- |
| ... |
| Z098 |
| Z099 |
| Z100 |
| AA001 |
| AA002 |
| AA003 |
| ... |

The zero start for the sequence also means it doesn't get `[` when it's exhausted the new, expanded range (which is now 70300 values); but it does still loop around and from `ZZ100` to `AA0001`. You can set a `maxvalue` on the sequence to make it error instead.

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Jj9udXOA)

If that still isn't enough values then you can continue the mechanism; this time I've put it in a function to make it easier to modify and test, and expand later if needed:

```
create or replace function get_seq_str
return varchar2 as
  pragma udf;
  l_seq number;
begin
  l_seq := one_seq.nextval;
  return
    case when l_seq >= (27 * 26 * 100)
      then chr(mod(trunc(l_seq / (27 * 26 * 100)) - 1, 26) + 65) end
    || case when l_seq >= (26 * 100)
      then chr(mod(trunc(l_seq / (26 * 100)) - 1, 26) + 65) end
    || chr(mod(trunc(l_seq / 100), 26) + 65)
    || to_char(mod(l_seq, 100) + 1, 'FM000');
end;
/
```

then called from SQL as

```
select get_seq_str from dual
```

or can also be called directly for assignment from PL/SQL.

Again it'll run out eventually and loop (after 1895400 values) and you can define the sequence with `minvalue 0 start with 0 maxvalue 1895399` to get an error instead, or expand the logic in the logic to have more characters available.

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/8wGj_iRQ)

---

This still seems unnecessarily complicated when you could just use a plain numeric sequence value (and/or convert to this form for display purposes). You could also generate a table of all the possible values in advance, which could avoid gaps if those are an issue for you; when you need a value you can find the next available one and mark it as used in that table. That would serialise access though, as only one session could get a value at a time.

Comment: after Z100 can we add some logic to start at AA001 to overcome the 2600 value limitation

Comment: @psaraj12 - yes, but it gets messier and harder to maintain. I've added some thoughts anyway.

Comment: I am planning to generate a table of all the possible values in advance, as suggested by you at the end. Appreciate your efforts put in explanation.